# Screen Resolution CentOS 8 - VMware

Tags: centos, vmware, screen-resolution, centos8

System: CentOS8

I am using VMware ESXi

I can easily change a resolution to 1400x1050, but after reboot/shutdown returns to default resolution (800x600).
I set the `.vmx` file settings:

```
svga.vramSize = "67108864"
svga.minWidth="1400"
svga.minHeight="1050"
svga.maxWidth="1400"
svga.maxHeight="1050"
svga.autodetect = "FALSE" -- changing to "TRUE" it doesn't help either
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... So just for information.
Solution (workaround) is:

When logging in (entering the password), select the cog and change from:

**Standard (Wayland display server)
to
Classic (X11 display server)**

then the last selected correct resolution will automatically be loaded.

*This option will also be remembered after reboot (Classic)*

Comment: That didn't work for me; it's still reverting to 800x600 after reboot :@

Comment: I do not have a "cog" at sign in.  I looked and found an example of the cog on the web but I do not have that.

Comment: I think this has more to do with the 'raw' setup of the Azure CentOS image.  I had to install Gnome from command line.  Not sure if there is some sort of video card driver or X display config I need to install.